# How to set AM/PM in SQL to_date?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to sort query results between two dates. How do I set the date to define either AM/PM?

The specific dates are in `YYYY-mm-dd hh:mi` format.

```
AND (cr.COMPLETED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE( :Start_Date , 'YYYY-mm-dd hh:mi') AND TO_DATE( :End_Date , 'YYYY-mm-dd hh:mi'))
```

I tried entering numbers greater than 12 (military time) but I get this error `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12`

Is there a way to specify AM/PM with `YYYY-mm-dd hh:mi` date format?

Comment: which is it? [tag:mysql] or [tag:oracle]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the addition of the 24 in the date format specification.  That will allow you to enter 24 hour time:

```
AND (cr.COMPLETED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE( :Start_Date , 'YYYY-mm-dd hh24:mi') AND TO_DATE( :End_Date , 'YYYY-mm-dd hh24:mi'))
```

Alternatively you can use am/pm designators with this line:

```
AND (cr.COMPLETED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE( :Start_Date , 'YYYY-mm-dd hh:mi am') AND TO_DATE( :End_Date , 'YYYY-mm-dd hh:mi am'))
```

Here's a way to try to detect which of the two formats to use.  If it finds either AM or PM in the string it will assume the AM/PM designation otherwise it will expect 24 hour notation:

```
CASE
  WHEN regexp_like( :START_DATE, '((AM)|(PM))','i') 
    THEN to_date(:START_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi am')
  ELSE to_date(:START_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
END
```

Comment: will adding the 'hh24' work even if the format of the date specifically includes AM/PM?

Comment: No,  I believe the format spec either needs to be `hh24:mi[:ss]` or `hh:mi[:ss] am`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you or anyone else were interested in doing this in MySQL, but if you wanted to:

```
AND (cr.COMPLETED_DATE BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT( :Start_Date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p' )
                           AND DATE_FORMAT( :End_Date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p')
```